# DIY AC Line Splitter

Tags: wiring, cord-and-plug, multimeter

As a fresh DIY-er (just moved into my own house), I've purchased a digital clamp multimeter.
Learned the hard way that in order to utilize the clamp to measure current, the supply line needs to be split.

I'd rather build a line splitter instead of settling for a product. The clamp has a 20A limit - research indicates a 12/2 wire with an equally rated male-female power plug should suffice.

Has anyone created a line splitter before - Any precautions/best practices? Thanks

Comment: While we're indeed a DIY site, our theme is home improvement. I'm afraid this topic falls outside that scope. You might try http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think a question about using a clamp meter to measure current draw of a standard home electric system is on topic.  He's asking about two tools that any residential electrician would use all the time.

Comment: Putting the issue of it being for computers and not a home aside, building complex tools is not the same as using them. :)

Comment: just split an extension cord in the middle; no wire cutting or dangerous operations involved.

Comment: Right, just get a 1' extension cord of the "flat" type, and carefully exacto down the grooves, erring toward the ground wire in the middle.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks, didn't know about that forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a line splitter like this with a heavy duty male and female three prong plug and three 14g wires - white, black, and green. 12/2 romex will have a bare copper ground, and I didn't want any exposed wire so I used actual green insulated wire for ground.

Use plugs that have an integrated wire clamp so the connections are secure, and don't leave it plugged in for longer than you need to make your measurements because the exposed separate conductors are not as strong and make a trip or tangle hazard.  This is a special tool, not a permanent extension cord.

I know you said you didn't want a product, but if someone does, there are devices like this that are made to do just what you want in a safe, listed way.  It has one loop for regular measurements and a second loop that multiplies the signal 10x (it just as 10 loops of the wire there).

[image]

Comment: I have a male female cord also only about 1 foot long so I can trouble shoot lighting fixtures I use. My handy tool at least every other week.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - thanks, good advice. Will stop by Home Depot this weekend to prepare for the same.

Comment: I never imagined there would be a factory-made tool for this. The 10x loop is also a good idea. But I think a complete volt-ampere-watt-watthour meter w/ a male and female plug is a better idea and probably costs the same.