# How to measure power usage on a 120V circuit that can go up to 20 Amps?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, generator

I want to measure the power coming out of a 120V outlet that can go up to 20 Amps.  A standard household circuit is limited to 15 amps but this is a special situation where we're running our own temporary power grid off a generator. Specifically, the plugs are "NEMA 5-20P" where one of the blades can be slanted.

All the watt-meters I find online only support up to 1800W/15A since they're meant for home use.  Usually, that'll be fine, but situations where we start drawing more than 15 amps is exactly when I want to know how much I'm using.

Any ideas on to build something that can measure current/power when it can go up to 20A? At this point off the shelf doesn't seem like an option so I figure I'll make to make my own and would love some tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you get your paws on a clampmeter and plug adapter for same?

Comment: @DanielGriscom thanks! At this point, I figure I'll have to make my own meter, so I tweaked the question to reflect that and make it less about "shopping" =)

Comment: This is a dupe of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131012/diy-ac-line-splitter, basically (can't VtC it any longer)

Comment: if you get a *current transformer* to make your own.  *be warned* ... these devices are *EXTREMELY* dangerous.  they can have *DEADLY* voltages.  if you don't thoroughly understand how they work and are wired, don't mess with them.

Comment: 20 amp circuits are quite common and not the exception is residential in fact the required circuits in the kitchen, bath and laundry are all 20 amps, I wire more homes with 20 amp circuits more often than 15. If you want to check your current draw there are many meters under 100$ that can accurately measure in the +100 amp range including fluke meters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DIY AC Line Splitter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131012/diy-ac-line-splitter)

Comment: Not a duplicate but as I said in a comment on that post a male female cord cap set and a clamp meter will allow a meter to be used to measure current. A clamp meter is needed to do this and most clamp meters have much higher ability’s than 20 amps.

Comment: Kill-a-Watts will measure up to 20A, even though they will complain if current flow is over 15A. However they are not made with turned-neutral NEMA 5-20 plugs or sockets.

Comment: I would be purchasing a professional tool like this [Fluke Clamp Multimeter](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00AQKIEXY/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_k4ywDbJV8A38Q). It's capable of up to 400 Amps. I think this is your best bet.